# What is a word that means related to moons?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a word that means "relating to moons" or "pertaining to moons".

The context of the sentence is "*I need to make a **intermoonary** injection burn in 10 seconds*".

I'm looking for a word like *intergalactic*, *interstellar* or *interplanetary* but relating to moons. Not explicitly Luna, our moon, which would be lunar.

The options I've looked at are lunar (which only relates to Earth's moon), satellitic and moonary. None of them seem right.

Comment: If there is such a word, I certainly don't know it (or can't call it to mind). I'm not keen on ***satellitic*** either (nor is my Google spell-checker, though it *is* in OED). We're likely to need it more in the coming decades though, so +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: This question should be asked in *Astronomy* or *Space Exploration* Stack Exchange.

Comment: If we were determined to use something other than lunar I would suggest something like **selenac** (or selenial, selenian, what have you), refering to Selene the moon goddess. (we still use iris so I don't think its out of the question)

Comment: I thought perhaps *interorbital*, but apparently that means something entirely different.

Comment: @yeshe - going from *luna* to *selene* is like going from *Mercury* (Roman) to *Hermes* (Greek), so you can argue that the *periapsis* at Mercury is the *periherm* and likewise *periselene* at the Moon.  In other words, you choose the right pantheon for the prefix.  *inter-* comes from Latin, so switching to the Greek pantheon doesn't really make sense.    Problem is that Latin doesn't suggest a good term for *satellite* because there was no such concept.  *Interorbital* seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not convinced we couldn't use *lunar* in this context. While *lunar* originated with reference to our specific moon, so did *solar* (from our Sol/Sun), yet we refer to *our solar system*, and even [NASA](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/profile.cfm?Object=Beyond) mentions, "There are billions of stars and countless solar systems in our galaxy."

I think it's perfectly reasonable to describe an eclipse observed from the surface of another planet, by that planet's moon, using the term *lunar eclipse*. The term would take on a relative meaning, depending on the planet from which the eclipse was observed. It's not like we call it a ***Lunar*** eclipse, after all.

Now, whether "*interlunar*", or similar, could be coined, is another matter. However, I think a reader would immediately understand what is being conveyed.

Comment: *Interlunar*, as I know from years of well-spent youth reading all the science fiction I could lay my hands on, would be well-received by other such readers. It is the usual term in that genre of fiction for expressions such as the OP's example. A minor point is that 'interlunar' has currency in mainstream uses, designating the period between the old and the new moon.

Comment: This will probably be marked as correct, but I feel like this is an example of the inadequacy of the English language. We've adopted and applied meaning to foreign words to the point where we're changing the meaning of the original word.

Comment: @Coomie - Some might prefer to look at it as the versatility or adaptability of the English language, but I definitely see your point. To the usage at hand - in a world in which the action you're describing is common-place, it would likely have some sort of acronym and/or slang associated with it, anyway. Depending on the scope (and tone) of your writing, you could have fun and coin something that may feel more appropriate. It could even be abstracted to have nothing at all to do with the moons, and simply use the moons as the frame of reference for that abstracted concept.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can use the term ***orbit injection*** to describe a maneuver that changes the nature of your orbit. I imagine this would be true for most maneuvers between moons, but I can also imagine a strange situation where two moons are actually following the same orbit.

> *Orbit insertion* is a general term for a maneuver that is more than a small correction. It may be used for a maneuver to change a transfer orbit or an ascent orbit into a stable one, but also to change a stable orbit into a descent: *descent orbit insertion*. Also the term **orbit injection** is used, especially for changing a stable orbit into a transfer orbit, e.g. *trans-lunar injection* (TLI), *trans-Mars injection* (TMI) and *trans-Earth injection* (TEI).
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_maneuver#Transfer_orbits)</sub>